# ng-repeat filter, display message when filter has removed object

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

Some of my people are ninjas, some are not.

If they are not, I'd like to display the `this guy isn't a ninja` message.

Right now, nothing is displaying. Am I using the filter incorrectly?

I'd like to handle this in the view, without adding any new logic to my controller.

```
<div ng-repeat="person in people | filter: {job: 'ninja'}">
    <div ng-show="person">
        This guy is a ninja
    </div>
    <div ng-show="!person">
        This guy isn't a ninja <--Not showing 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your `filter` would create a new array with only ninjas and remove anything else that isn't, so they will never show up. (You can also use `ng-switch` if you want to use pre-defined jobs, here is a demo: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/iZwuTStNRJTOq1GtKHGo?p=preview))

Answer (score 0):

You are not looking for a filter, you are looking for a "ng-show" statement:

```
<div ng-repeat="person in people">
    <div ng-show="person.job === 'ninja'">
        This guy is a ninja
    </div>
    <div ng-show="person.job !== 'ninja'">
        This guy isn't a ninja
    </div>
</div>
```

**> [Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/use1n3em/)**

Answer (score 0):

You are currently filtering out every person that does not have the job `ninja`. If you want `ninja` and `non-ninja` to appear in the ng-repeat you will have to remove the filter and use `ng-show` to determine what is showed.

```
<div ng-repeat="person in people">
    <div ng-show="person.job === 'ninja'">
        This guy is a ninja
    </div>
    <div ng-show="person.job !== 'ninja'">
        This guy isn't a ninja 
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Moving with these cases and handle with ng-show I will not recommend as good practice as you might be the encounter with more cases in future so you may go with the switch cases and when you filter the data you only left with filter result array which is new array after filter

```
<div ng-repeat="person in people ">
    <div ng-switch="person">
  <div ng-switch-when="ninja">this is Ninja</div>
  <div ng-switch-default>this is not ninja</div>
</div>
```